# Pre-fill Rails HTML form with variable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, input

I am trying to implement a pre-filled HTML form in Ruby on Rails where `@product.price` variable will be pre-filled. I don't really think a textarea is the one that I am looking for.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to be able to work.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.number_field :priceOffer, :input_html => {:value => @product.price }, class:"form-control" %>
</div>
```

Any suggestions why it couldn't work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [`number_field`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/number_field), you pass in number fields value, class and other options in a single block so try this:

```
<%= f.number_field :priceOffer, :value => @product.price, class:"form-control" %>
```

Comment: That's the right one! Thanks for referring me to the API. At least now I know how to read the api documentation better. I was just simply trying around but couldnt get it work! Have a nice day!